# Are my if-conditions correct to sum up the even fibonacci numbers up to 4 million?

Tags: c++, function, recursion, sum, fibonacci

> Starting from 1 and 2, compute the sum of all even fibonacci numbers (while these numbers are smaller or equal to 4 million)

I am trying to sum all even fibonacci numbers up to `4e6`, but it doesn't give me anywhere the right result, and I don't understand where I've messed up. In my mind, the conditions for the `if` are correct.

My `fibonacci()` function, and my function to sum the even numbers up, is below.

```
int fibonacci(int k) //compute the k-th fibonacci number (with EulerProject formula)
{
    if (k == 1 || k == 2)
    {
        return k;
    }
    {
        return (fibonacci(k-1)+ fibonacci(k-2));
    }
}
```

```
int evenfibonacci()
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int k = 1; fibonacci(k)<=4e6;) {
        if (fibonacci(k)%2 == 0 ) {
            result += fibonacci(k);
            k++;
        } else {
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does your `evenfibonacci` function return the `int` its signature promises?

Comment: Your compiler should have complained about the issue @NathanPierson identified.

Comment: Does your computer or platform have enough stack space for the fibonacci recursion?  You may want to switch to iteration instead.

Comment: It doesn't, I guess?

But I do have a main function where I just did `std::cout << evenfibonacci() << std::endl;`

Comment: Your `fibonacci()` implementation is extremely inefficient.

Comment: Side note: look up "memoization". If you have to brute-force each and every number in the fibonacci sequence over and over again, you're unnecessarily burning up a lot of computer time.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I am pretty new to coding so I don't really understand what you're trying to say, but if I understood it correctly, I do think so as I can definitely compute the fibonacci(33) which is already 5.something million so more than 4 million

Comment: `evenfibonacci()` is calling `fibonacci(k)` 3 times per loop iteration, that is incredibly inefficient, especially as `k` gets into higher numbers. Each iteration should call `fibonacci(k)` 1 time and cache the result into a variable for use as needed. Better if you can just get rid of `fibonacci()` altogether and use an iterative approach to calculating the numbers as you loop

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you! As I've said in another comment I am pretty new to coding, btu I will definitely take a look at this. Haven't had it in class so far

Comment: @RemyLebeau would it be better if I e.g calculate the k for which the condition that `fibonacci(k) <= 4e6` is broken and then just say k < that value in the `evenfibonacci()`?

Comment: you can call it only once and save the result in a variable

Comment: @giuli0110 yes, that would eliminate one call to `fibonacci(k)`. But that leaves 2 other calls, which can then be consolidated.

Comment: The more efficient way to do this is by using a loop and an array to store the values, instead of using a recursive function

Comment: @giuli0110:  Every time you call a function, you push the return address onto the stack as well as any local variables that need to be preserved.  They stay on the stack until the execution leaves the function; building up a large stack.

Comment: You don't need to do the full calculation of each fibanocci number. Just keep track of the last two; that's all the information you need to calculate the next one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`evenfibonacci()` is declared as returning an `int` value, but does not actually `return` anything, which is *undefined behavior*.  Thus, the return value is always *indeterminate*, it ends up returning random garbage, which is why you never get a good result.

You need to add a `return` statement, eg:

```
int evenfibonacci()
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int k = 1; fibonacci(k) <= 4e6; ++k) {
        if (fibonacci(k) % 2 == 0) {
            result += fibonacci(k);
        }
    }
    return result; // <-- ADD THIS
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/I2kdgE)

That being said, calling `fibonacci(k)` 3 times per loop iteration is very inefficient, calculating the same values over and over, especially for higher values of `k`.  You should call it only 1 time per loop, eg:

```
int evenfibonacci()
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int k = 1; k <= 33; ++k) {
        int value = fibonacci(k);
        if (value % 2 == 0) {
            result += value;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/41gqKM)

Of course, a better solution would be to get rid of `fibonacci()` altogether, and instead use an iterative approach to calculating only new values per iteration, eg:

```
int evenfibonacci()
{
    int result = 2;
    int last[2] = {1, 2};
    for (int k = 3; k <= 33; ++k) {
        int value = last[0] + last[1];
        if (value % 2 == 0) {
            result += value;
        }
        last[0] = last[1];
        last[1] = value;
    }
    return result;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/vdUOLN)

Comment: Ah okay! Would you mind explaining what it did when I called it in the main function as follows *without* the `return result;`?

`int main() {

std::cout << evenfibonacci() << std::endl;

}`

Like why did I even get anything then?

Comment: I told you why in the 1st paragraph of my answer: "*the return value is always indeterminate*", which is *undefined behavior*.